# Can't pass mocked services to ConfigureTestServices in .NET Core API Integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I use minimal hosting API using .NET Core 7 with "flat" Program.cs such as:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddControllers();
services.AddSingleton<IBla, Bla>();
services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
// etc..
var app = builder.Build();
// etc..
app.Run();

public partial class Program { }
```

IFoo is injected in Bla constructor.
Then in a Nunit test (along with FakeItEasy), there is:

```
var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder => {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureTestServices(services => {
   
                    // register the service being tested
                    // Do I need it as it's already in Program.cs?
                    services.AddScoped<IBla, Bla>();


                    // WORKS
                    services.AddScoped<IFoo, FooFake>();

                    // DOES NOT WORK
                    //var foo = new Fake<IFoo>();
                    //foo.CallsTo(x => x.GetAsync(A<string>.Ignored))
                    //                .Returns(111);
                    //services.AddSingleton(foo);
                });
        });


var client = application.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/car/21");
```

When I use mocked service, the real implementation is invoked  (the one from Program.cs)
When I use Fake service it works fine but that's not what I want.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need it as it's already in Program.cs?

No, you don't if the registered implementation satisfies you

> WORKS

Yes, this will work, build-in DI uses the last registered implementation, with a caveat - if you will resolve `IEnumerable<IFoo>` somewhere it will contain the "unwanted" implementation too. Usual approach to mitigate that is to clean up the service collection before adding new registration:

```cs
services.RemoveAll(typeof(IFoo));
```

> DOES NOT WORK

Because `services.AddSingleton(foo);` will register service of type `Fake<IFoo>`. Not sure what `Fake` is but possibly you want something like `services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(foo);` or `services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(foo.SomethingWhatReturnsFoo);` depending on how this particular fake/mock library works.

Comment: It worked when setting services.AddScoped<IFoo>(p => foo.FakedObject)
Thank you!